# Time/space complexity of string splitting/object creation in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity, space-complexity

I'am struggling to figure out the time complexity of a piece of code that I have that takes a user input from 1 line e.g open 1 0, and splits the input via spaces, then allows the user to create a new 'account' object on the heap. I am thinking it is an O(n^2) operation as it contains 2 while loops, plus an additional function call, this could be completely wrong.

```
int main(){

    std::vector <std::string> parameters;
    std::string userCommand;

    // Make a new account manager object for a new user
    AccountManager accounts = AccountManager();

    while (userCommand != "exit"){

        parameters.clear(); // Clear ready for next command
        std::cout << std::endl << ">>> ";

        std::getline(std::cin, userCommand);
        char* cstr = new char[userCommand.length() + 1];
        strcpy(cstr, userCommand.c_str());

        char* token;
        token = strtok(cstr, " ");

        while (token != nullptr){
            parameters.push_back(token);
            token = strtok(nullptr, " ");
        }

        // This calls a function that creates a creates a new object on the heap
        accounts.openAccount(parameters[1], parameters[2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: rather than hopping into character arrays to use a destructive, non-reentrant function like `strtok` to split on spaces, take the line, stick it into a `std::istringstream` and then parse the string stream with `>>`. Eg: `std::istringstream strm(userCommand); std::string token; while (strm >> token) { parameters.push_back(token); }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complexity is linear in the total user input length on both space and time.

All the individual operations iterate over user input only a constant amount of times, including the inner loop. Therefore with `n` the total length of user input time the time complexity is `Theta(n)`.

Similarly memory is only used to store a constant multiple of the user input length, implying `Theta(n)` space complexity.

---

This is assuming that the `AccountManager` operations which you didn't elaborate on are not dominating.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, my worse case function in my AccountManager class is a search function that goes onto call a BST and search for a value (BST that supports duplicates). So would this affect my time complexity and space?

Comment: @patricebailey1998 If you insert into that tree in `openAccount`, yes. It will add a factor `log(n)` to the worst-case time complexity for the key lookup in the tree. Space complexity will not be affected. This is assuming that the tree is a typical balanced search tree implementation.

Comment: @user11732522 Assuming I understood you correctly space is 0(n) and time would be O(nlogn)?

Comment: @patricebailey1998 Yes probably, with some assumptions on the details.

Comment: Ive just read if you have logn and n then just just 0(n) for time and not O(nlogn) sorry is this correct?, as we take the highest bound

Comment: @patricebailey1998 No, I said "add a factor" by which I mean go from `n` to `n*log(n)`. The key lookup will also have the factor `n`, since comparison of strings needs to iterate over the full length worst-case.

Comment: I forgot to mention, its a red-black tree so its self balancing, so It would just be O(NLogN), correct? sorry for the spam

Comment: @patricebailey1998 Yes, as above, probably, assuming there isn't anything unusual in the imeplementation.

Comment: Ok thank you, and no i dont think there is its just the code in main from the question above, that actually has another if statement inside it (that i didnt include otherwise it might be conisdered spam as there is lots of commands) that goes onto call a search function in AccountManager object that calls a BST search

Answer (score 0):

Let’s assume `n` is the number of times the user submitted an input.

**Time complexity:**

For each `n` we are iterating over a number of parameters, let's call them `m`, however in the sample code provided above it seems like you only expect two parameters meaning the iteration here is always constant. If the number of parameters are variant and/or increasing the time complexity would be `O(n*m)`, but if `m = 2`, `O(2*n)` becomes `O(n)` linear time.

**Space complexity:**

For each user input `n` we are creating a new `account`, it's ambiguous how the new account is created or stored from the provided code, but it's clear that for every user input we create a single new `account`, meaning the space complexity here is also `O(n)`. The space complexity for all other variables are constant and therefore doesn’t affect the overall space complexity.

**Note:** the `openAccount` method could be storing accounts using a data-structure, depending on which one, the time-complexity will be affected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer openAccount makes a new Account (separate class) object on the heap using a smart pointer, and is stored in a vector of smart pointers, would this change the space/time?

Comment: @patricebailey1998 The space complexity is not affected, because it relies on the increase of storage per input size, and the pointers/vector doesn't change that, we still have one `account` per entry. The time complexity for the vector's `pust_back()` operation is `O(1)`, so no change either. however, if you're using `insert()` (which is `O(n)` complexity ) the overall time complexity increases to `O(n*n)`. Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: I have been using emplace back, instead of pushback is it the same case for emplace back as well?  And when you mean O(n*n) does this just equal too O(n^2)? thanks,

Comment: @patricebailey1998 Yes, [emplace_back](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/emplace_back/) has the same constant time complexity. Also yes; `O(n*n)` and `O(n^2)` are identical.